# Override HTML export defaults

Tags: org-mode

I use orgmode to capture meetings minutes and I do HTML exports afterwards to publish them on our team's website.

I would like to set some export options automatically. But the defaults created by org-insert-export-options-template do not suit my needs, I would like to tweek them and I could not find the right way to do this in the documentation. I understand this should be easy so I'm puzzled to be stuck by this issue.

Can someone help me out ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things you can customize for HTML export:

- [HTML preamble and postamble](http://orgmode.org/manual/HTML-preamble-and-postamble.html#HTML-preamble-and-postamble)
- [Style (CSS)](http://orgmode.org/manual/CSS-support.html#CSS-support)
- You can customize the defaults so you don't need to add an options template (`org-customize` - Export - Export General)
- XML declaration (`org-customize` - Export - HTML)

Comment: Yes, org-customize  -> Export -> Export General is what I needed.

I'll digg more inside org-customize, thanks